# ProgressBar and progressBarStyleHorizontal padding

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar, padding

I have a progress bar defined thanks to this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_article_progressBar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_article_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I run it, some padding is added above and below the `ProgressBar`

[image]

It doesn't seem very natural.

Is it the normal style of a horizontal `ProgressBar`? If no, how can I fix it?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace

```
 <ProgressBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_article_progressBar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

Via

```
 <ProgressBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_article_progressBar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

Comment: This fix seems a bit... Dirty! Will it work with any device? :-)

Comment: If you don't want to use android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp ,android:layout_marginTop="-4dp" then try to use
`android:minHeight="20dip" 
android:maxHeight="20dip"`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the second solution is not working (the blank space is bigger)

Comment: It was just random height.you need to set that property as per your need. You can use 10 or 12 dp

Comment: Cheers mate, I will go with your answer!

Comment: wont work on some apis

Comment: a better solution is
<ProgressBar style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" android:layout_height="4dp"/>

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/fragment_article_progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is the same as Krupa Patel one. If this solution compatible with any screen size?

Comment: Ya It will be compatible with any screen sizes.

Comment: This is not compatible with every device.

Comment: wont work on some apis